# DRF foreign primary key that auto increments with nested serializers for cascade insert

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to insert a Conversation model that has a child class to Message model.
I also want it to use a single Viewset method for the saving.
The Message has a foreign key to the primary key of Conversation.

I'm looking for something similar to the java + spring class implementation wherein the Parent references the Child class.
The Parent and Child have an auto_increment annotation. Spring JPA save is called and the insert is cascaded.

Parent Class:

```
int id;
Child reference;
```

Child Class:

```
int child_id;
int parent_id;
```

Service Method:

```
parent.setReference(child);
jpa.save(parent); // both parent and child is inserted
```

Is there something like this for Django Rest Framework? Or Django Framework?

json:

```
{
  "model": "conversation",
  "id": auto_increment,
  "title": "chat",
  "message": {
    "model": "message",
    "conversation_id": value from id in conversation model,
    "message": "hi"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [writable nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).  Also all django models have an auto-increment primary key by default, or you can add your own auto-increment field.

> By default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create create() and/or update() methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved.

Here is an example of a writable nested serializer using Albums and Tracks.

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('id', 'order', 'title', 'duration', 'album_id')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('id', 'album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album

>>> data = {
    'id': 1,
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'id': 1, 'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245, 'album_id': 1},
        {'id': 2, 'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264, 'album_id': 1},
        {'id': 3, 'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159, 'album_id': 1},
    ],
}
>>> serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
>>> serializer.save()
<Album: Album object>
```

Comment: is there a simpler way to implement this? also, how would you access the variables in `album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)` if you need to?

Comment: After saving, a serializer will set the `instance` attribute to the saved object, so `serializer.instance` would return the album after saving in this case.

Comment: what if there is some business logic that needs to be done in the `for loop` for `tracks_data` that requires a value from `album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)`? Would something like `album.artist` be possible?

Comment: Yeah album is usable

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to have the "id" in the json.

Remove it from the DRF serializer, and django ORM will auto-increment the id for every new record. By default, the id field of the model gets incremented automatically.

Comment: i added the "id" there for context